# Server software - Which to run as root?

Tags: shell, permissions, debian

Here is a list of my stack:

> Nginx UWSGI Tomcat Solr Virtualenv Supervisor

I'm trying to set up my server correctly and I am wondering which of these should be run as root and which should have their own user accounts. If they shouldnt run as user accounts, should every one have its own account, or should programs like Nginx and Uwsgi be grouped under one account called "web" for example.

Any feedback on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not run any of those services as **root**. I personally use each of them under its own user account.

Use **root** only to perform installations or other maintenance tasks. But not to run any services or user programs.

Comment: Ok. Now, should I group multiple programs under one new user account, says "Solr and Tomcat" under "search" or "Nginx and Uwsgi" under web?

Comment: That's up to you. I would prefer separate accounts for each service, but I can't think of anything wrong in grouping your services under certain users for simplicity. That's probably up to your system administrator. However she prefers to manage her servers and services.